# How to render Mapbox Vector Tiles from OSM data?

Tags: mapnik, mapbox, vector-tiles

I'd like to render my own vector tiles in the Mapbox Vector Tile format (MVT) format using OpenStreetMap data (ultimately for use with Mapbox's hot Mapbox GL JS client renderer).

Is TileStache + Mapnik + [mapnik-vector-tile](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile) + PostGIS the way to do this? How does one configure Mapnik to render MVT tiles?

Comment: See the Mapzen way https://github.com/mapzen/vector-datasource/wiki/Mapzen-Vector-Tile-Service then define your layers

Answer (score 2):

If you just want OpenStreetMap data in Mapbox Vector Tile format, MapZen provides this service for free: https://mapzen.com/projects/vector-tiles/

All the tooling required to do it is open: https://github.com/mapzen/vector-datasource